# Need help renaming files referring to a CSV whilst dealing with duplicate names etc

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a program to rename a large quantity of files according to a CSV provided by a client. The CSV contains in:
Row [0] - The current name to be replaced
Row [1] - The name to replace it with

I have encountered issues with duplicate file names within the CSV in the past, in this scenario I would like to automatically add "_*n*" (*n* = duplicate number) to the file names when appropriate.

The files and the CSV are all located in the same folder.

```
import os
import sys
import csv

print('Hey')

def rename_files(csv_filename):
    with open('rename_csv.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        files_mapping = {}
        new_filenames = set()

        for row in csvreader:

            name = row[0] + '.wav'
            new = row[1] + '.wav'

            if new in new_filenames:
                raise Exception(
                    'Found duplicate filename {} for file {}'.format(new, name)
                )

            new_filenames.add(new)
            files_mapping['name'] = new

        for name, new in files_mapping.items():
            if os.path.exists(name):
                print('\n' + 'renaming ' + name)
                os.rename(name, new)

            else:
                print('\n' + name + " does not exist")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rename_files(sys.argv[1])
```

expected result is that the files labelled (in this case...) 1.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav, etc. will be renamed to a.wav, b.wav, c.wav, etc. as per the CSV. Instead it seems to run but not change any file names.

Terminal output: 
 Hey

name does not exist

Comment: Your script has obvious indentation errors. Please [edit] it so it actually runs. (On the desktop version of this site, select the pasted code and type ctrl-K.)

Comment: What do the first few lines in the CSV look like, and do those files exist in the current directory?

Comment: Hi tripleee,  thanks for the formatting tip (first time poster haha),
CSV as below:
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
5,e

current filenames are (1 to 26) + '.wav'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrectly building the files mapping dictionary. I think on this line

```
files_mapping['name'] = new
```

you meant to refer to the `name` variable - so replace it with

```
files_mapping[name] = new
```